# Can anyone explain why this code concatenates rather than adds the numerical values?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, addition, parseint

So, to start off, I know this code is messy, please bear with me, but can anyone explain why this keeps concatenating the entered information rather than adding the numerical values after being passed through `parseInt()`?

```js
var sol = 0;
var n = 0;

while(n !== null)
{

parseInt(n = prompt("Please enter a number to be added onto stack"));
  if(n != null || n != NaN)
  {
    sol = parseInt(sol);
    sol += n;
  }

}
console.log(sol);
```

Comment: You have to set `n = parseInt(...)`. Functions don't modify variables that way in JS.

Comment: @bbbbbb I knew I was doing something stupid haha, thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prompt()` returns a string.

`parseInt()` accepts a string and returns a number.

You aren't doing anything with the return value of the first `parseInt`. This means `n` is a string.  So when you do `sol += n` you are adding a string and number together, and javascript assumes that you meant to concatenate strings together, since math with a string and number doesn't make any sense.

You probably meant to do:

```
n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number to be added onto stack"));
```

Comment: Depending on background, it might be worth mentioning that JS functions can't modify their arguments. JS passes arguments by object-reference. If you're used to functions that change some variable state, this may be confusing.